# How were the DRDs on Moya operated?

Tags: farscape, behind-the-scenes

On Farscape, Moya was serviced by a fleet of Diagnostic Repair Drones, or DRDs for short. I've been trying to find out how those DRDs that featured on the show - One-Eye, DRD Pike and 1812, and the nameless others - were operated by the show's technical crew.

Were they radio-controlled, like a toy car? Were they pulled around on wires? Was there some over-complicated arrangement with magnets pulled around under the set's floor? Were there tiny puppeteers in green-screen suits that were erased in post-production?

I've Googled around for it, but all I could find was a lot of sites selling DRD replicas, some even looking similar to the original, or YouTube videos helping you build one on your own from a kit or completely from scratch. No behind-the-scenes information about how they did it on the show.

Comment: I'd imagine they were remote controlled - but all the Farscape wikia has to say on the matter is that "they were not made from bicycle helmets".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**DRDs or Diagnostic Repair Drones which appeared in the Farscape series were a mixture of remote controlled vehicle and computer programmable device. Note the remote controls next to the device and the internal motherboard. Given they were produced by Jim Henson Studios I am not surprised they were hand made with loving detail. They were quite expensive to build and design with "fully functional" ones cost over $10,000 each.**

[image]

- The only name I could find associated with the design of DRDs was Andre Potappel who now works at Gizmo Workshop in Sydney Australia (pictured above)
- They had sophisticated programming such as the chase lights on the bottom which moved fast when the DRD moved but slowed when they came to rest.

[image]

- There were two attachment points for peripherals with 7 variations, the claw, the projector arm, the "gatling gun", the injector, the "canon", the plow and the sprayer.
- One had movable eyes which could move independent of each, but most only had eyes that were slaved together.
- The single most functional one had full forward/reverse motion, speed regulated baselights, full motion projector arm, working claw, working "wings", slaved eye stalks and pop-up "siren" lights.

[image]

- The more advanced units had plates that could be added or removed along with LED plates for different lighting when a plate was missing.
- Though it was hard to tell the devices were quite large, much larger than they appeared as the moved through the corridors of Moya.

[image]

Given the expense of the fully functioning DRDs, I suspect they made varying levels of technical sophistication depending on what was needed when filming was being done.

Comment: Excellent answer. Where'd you get all the information from?

Comment: Concur - please add your sources!